# React D3 x-axis text tilt - how to access transform property? tickFormat?

Tags: svg, reactjs, react-d3

I am using the Bar Chart in React-D3 :

My x-axis labels are slamming into each other, and I want to rotate them for readability,

an issue solved here for D3 without React rendering:
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

How do I fit this solution into the React-D3 package?

Where can I access the 'transform' property on 'text' or 'tick'?

I tried to pass in a prop as 'xAxisTransform' on BarChart.js, but it wasn't registering.

Should I use the tickFormat function to change the text on the ticks, if so, how?

Can/should ticks be manipulated from /common/axes/AxisTicks.js ?
https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3/issues/162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `node_modules/react-D3/common/axes/AxisTicks.js`
there's a switch statement (depending on where axis ticks are located on graph) where 
`transform = rotate(-65)`
can be added.

Make sure to declare `transform` as a variable:

```
render:function() {
    var props = this.props;

    var tr,
        ticks,
        scale,
        adjustedScale,
        textAnchor,
        transform,
        tickFormat,
        y0, y1, y2, dy, x0, x1, x2, dx;
```

and at bottom where the element is created by React and returned add it to the style object:

```
React.createElement("text", {
      strokeWidth: "0.01", 
      dy: dy, x: x1, y: y1, 
      style: {stroke:props.tickTextStroke, fill:props.tickTextStroke}, 
          textAnchor: textAnchor,
          transform: transform
      }
```

This solves the immediate problem, however, hacks the shared/common attributes for all D3 chart axis ticks.

If there is a better way, please post!